# Is row level locking atomic in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, queue, worker

I have a table in PostgreSQL which I'd like to treat as a queue. I have some selection criteria which I'm using to lock and then delete rows from the table like this:

```
DELETE FROM queue
WHERE itemid = (
  SELECT itemid
  FROM queue
  ORDER BY itemid
  WHERE some_column='some value'
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
RETURNING *;
```

How does row locking work in PostgreSQL? When the `SELECT` query is executed will it lock all matching rows atomically? I'm asking this because grouping is important for me and I want to process all rows where `some_column='some value'` in the same worker.

**Clarification:** What I really want to know is whether it can happen that two workers are executing the same query (the one above) for the same parameters (`some value`) and one of them locks a few rows for update and the other worker picks up the rest. This is what I'd like to avoid. What I expect to happen is that one of the workers will get all the rows (if row locking is atomic) and the other one gets nothing. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two of your queries are running concurrently, each of them can return and delete some of the rows in the table. In that sense, your query is not atomic.

You should serialize your processes, either outside the database or using PostgreSQL [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS).

Comment: Thanks. Advisory locks are a good idea, but we ended up using a job table for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working on a queuing table, be sure to check out SKIP LOCK:

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/